# Monitor print queue and merge jobs into one using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have an automated app which creates a set of outputs and sends them separately to the printer. Each page of the job is being sent as a separate print job which is undesirable, as it makes it almost impossible to use a PDF printer and convert create a single PDF file out of them.

I was wondering if there is a way to write a simple console or windows program that would receive these print jobs, merge them together and send the whole thing as one job to another printer. Is there anyway to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways I see to accomplish this.

- The first would be to modify the original program.  Have it drop PDFs off in a directory that is monitored by another program to do the combining.
- The second is to install a PDF print driver whose output is a file on the file system.  Every print job would output as a separate file.  Your program would then monitor that and combine as necessary
- The third way is to write your own print driver which takes the jobs and combines them.

However all of these "solutions" require you to be able to identify which page goes with which document and in what position of that document.  Honestly, without far more information, the best route would be to modify the originating program to just do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to merge print jobs, after they have been added to the queue.

- What application is producing these documents?
- What output format does it produce?
- What is your intended output format and destination?
  (printer/email/something else?)